# Implement an if in jekyll tag page

Tags: ruby, if-statement, jekyll

I have a page showing all the posts ordered by tag. The thing is that I only want some tags to be shown, not all of them. The thing would be after the "for tag in site.tags" implement an if like tag == x. I'm new to Jekyll and ruby and I don't know how to do it :/

```
{% capture site_tags %}{% for tag in site.tags %}{{tag | first }}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}


{% assign tag_words = site_tags | split:',' | sort %}


<ul class="tags">
{% for item in (0..site.tags.size) %}{% unless forloop.last %}
{% capture this_word %}{{ tag_words[item] }}{% endcapture %}
<li>
<a href="#{{ this_word | cgi_escape }}" class="tag">{{ this_word }}
<span>({{ site.tags[this_word].size }})</span>
</a>
</li>
{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
</ul>

<div>
{% for item in (0..site.tags.size) %}{% unless forloop.last %}
{% capture this_word %}{{ tag_words[item] }}{% endcapture %}
<h2 id="{{ this_word | cgi_escape }}">{{ this_word }}</h2>
{% for post in site.tags[this_word] %}{% if post.title != null %}
<div>
<span style="float: left;">
<a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
</span>
<span style="float: right;">
{{ post.date | date_to_string }}
</span>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
{% capture site_tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}...{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
```

Into this:

```
{% capture site_tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    {% if tag.title != 'excludedtag' %}...{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
```

And change 'excludedtag' to the tag title you want to exclude.